# How to use fn:replace with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to replace the XXXXX in the xml output with an affiliate link.  I was thinking that the replace function was an option but I could not get it to work correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>PayDotCom (By Popularity)</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Affiliate Link</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="marketplace/Product">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="aps"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="salespage"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is a snippet of the XML output which shows the XXXXX under Affiliate Link.

```
PayDotCom (By Popularity)

Score     Affiliate Link                            Name
52949.7   http://paydotcom.com/r/95330/XXXXX/       The Best Spinner
27828.8   http://paydotcom.com/r/10031/XXXXX/       My Data Team Global Data Entry &     Traditional Data Entry Jobs
12750.9   http://paydotcom.com/r/16329/XXXXX/       3WayLinks.net Subscription
10380.4   http://paydotcom.com/r/9912/XXXXX/        Instant Article Wizard
9438.49   http://paydotcom.com/r/98870/XXXXX/       The Smart Cash System - Make $4000 Per Week From Home
```

Let me know if I need to clarify more.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) is an XPath 2.0 function and is only available in XSLT 2.0 (and 3.0).

Your stylesheet is XSLT 1.0.

[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before) is an XPath 1.0 function that is available in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(salespage, 'XXXXX')"/>
```

Comment: How would using the substring-before() work? I wouldn't have the ability to switch the XXXXX out with another string. Should it be changed to an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0? If so, could it work with replace()?

Comment: Sure, move to XSLT 2.0 if you can. The only reason not to do so is if you are running on a platform where no XSLT 2.0 processor is available.

Comment: When switching to XSLT 2.0 `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
is that the only change to the code that is needed?  If it is 2.0 compliant, how can I get the replace() function to work correctly? Thanks again.

Comment: I was doing some more research... browsers do not support XSLT 2.0!  I did not know that.  OK.  Back to the original question, is there any way to replace the XXXXX in XSLT 1.0?  And if `substring-before()` works, then could you provide an example from the above code that replaces 'XXXXX' with 'AffiliateLink'? Thanks again.

Comment: I figured it out!!! Thank you Mads and Michael for your help! `<td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(salespage, 'XXXXX')"/>AffiliateLink/</td>`.  This will produce the ouput `http://paydotcom.com/r/95330/AffiliateLink/`.  It seems so obvious now.